# Add an image on top of a header image (Wordpress)

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm using the Wordpress theme "Illdy" (https://colorlib.com/illdy/)

I would like to add an image on top of the "jumbotron" header image. The image should be in the center of the jumbotron header, as well as be responsive.

If anyone could give me advice on how to do this, I would greatly appreciate it!

Thank you!

An example:

[Example image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlnb7.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried anything? Share your code, we will help you.

Comment: Have you fixed your problem @cvdm?

Comment: Hi RasmusGlenvig/Rohit - my URL is blackbirdit.co.za. I want to place an image instead of those words, on the header image. So the words "Gereformeerde Kerk Bloempark" should be replaced by a responsive image. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could do like this, and of course you need to change the top and left for the right positioning you want.

```css
.images {
  position: relative;
  top: 0;  
}
.image_1 { 
  position: relative; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
} 
.image_2 { 
  position: absolute; 
  top: 150px; 
  left: 200px; 
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="images">
  <img class="image_1" src="http://placehold.it/1500x600/ff0000/" alt="">
  <img class="image_2" src="http://placehold.it/700x300/000000/" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Hi RasmusGlenvig - my URL is blackbirdit.co.za. I want to place an image instead of those words, on the header image.

Comment: Yes, and I have shown you how to do it :) The code snippet that follows with my answer, shows an image on top of another.

Comment: Thank you Rasmus - I'm just not sure where exactly to put this code? I'm very new to styling Wordpress themes using code.

Comment: And of course you need to customize it so it fits your needs